# How to convert a normal font face to Unicode font

Tags: unicode, fonts

I want to know , how can we convert a font to Unicode font. I have PDF file in my native language but those text has been written in a specific font file (ttf file). So i want to convert those text into Unicode fonts.

So how can i convert those text into Unicode. Is there any free online software available or i have to write any software code in any language.

I have tried in PHP but not getting much more effective.

Answer (score 3):

Your question mixes several basic concepts (it is unclear whether you want to convert a *font* or the *text* it's written with), and I suggest you look a bit deeper into font technology before asking "then so how would I do it".

"Normal" fonts *are* using Unicode encoding. The "encoding" of a font describes which character *image* inside a font gets output for a given character *code*. A font can contain several encodings -- MacRoman, Windows Western -- and nowadays including a Unicode encoding is practically standard.

A font that does not comply to Unicode encoding (or any of the common ones) cannot be used without a translation from its character set to Unicode.

Your description suggests that the font in your PDF may be such a non-conforming font, so you need a table that maps its character codes to Unicode values. Use Google to see if someone else did this before you; if not, you will have to create the table yourself.

*However*.

Since your text comes out of a PDF, you cannot rely anymore on the encoding! If a PDF gets created, the software that does it is free to move characters around to different positions -- usually it creates a *subset font* from the original, and it can be convenient to reassign character codes. Friendly PDF creators may also include their own encoding in the PDF, but it is not *mandatory*. If it is missing, and your font is subsetted, then there is only one solution: you will have to create a translation table  *for that particular PDF*. It will *not* be of any use for other documents using "the same" font, because that most likely will have a different subset.